# Is there a way to persist iptables config using only default iptables on RHEL 7? (NOT iptables-services or firewallD!)

Tags: iptables, redhat, rhel7

I have a RHEL7 environment isolated from Internet in a DMZ network.

by default, only iptables is installed, neither iptables-service & firewalld is installed and CANNOT be installed from Internet. So all these commands are not effective:

```
(sudo) service iptables stop
(sudo) service firewalld stop
```

I'm able to use iptables -A to append rules, which are erased after every reboot. I'm looking for a way to let RHEL NOT to erase them after every reboot. But there seems to be no way to do so without using iptables-service or firewalld. Could you instruct me how to achieve this without Internet access?

Comment: Download the packages you need onto a USB stick, and walk them over to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.save
echo "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.save" > /etc/rc.d/rc.local
chmod u+x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
systemctl start rc-local
systemctl enable rc-local
```

Answer (score 0):

before reboot:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.save
```

after reboot:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.save
```

Comment: That should work manually, thanks a lot! But is there a startup save from which RHEL iptables will automatically load on rebooting?

Comment: sure, just use rc-local service https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-rc-local-service/